# How do I add TLS to a WCF service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I've been trying to add TLS to a WCF service, I've created.
Everything is OK until I try to access the service through https instead of http.
When adding the wcf service to the wcf test client, I get this:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from [THELINK] If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at [an MS link] Exchange Error    URI: [THELINK]
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '[THELINK]'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at [THELINK] that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.    The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.HTTP GET Error    URI: [THELINK]
>   There was an error downloading '[THELINK]'.    The request failed with
>   HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

Sorry about the link replacing, but I'm new and I don't have the reputation, it seems :)

Regards,
Morten

Comment: So have you enabled meta data publishing for your https endpoint?

Comment: Maybe this helps you? http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=281

Comment: the web.config would help

Answer (score 0):

do you have a

`<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="YourSerivceBehaviourName">
      <serviceMetadata  httpsGetEnabled="true" /> <-- this bit ?
    ...
  ...`

being referenced by your

`<service name="...." behaviorConfiguration="YourSerivceBehaviourName">`

or a

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

in your web.config?

the Test client will also moan if the certificate isn't a real one I have found.. ie a self certed one for testing.
but the 403 seems to suggest that whatever credentials you are supplying are incorrect, what is the clientCredentialType set to in the SSL binding?

and what happens if you hit the link in a browser with customerrors off.. 
this might give you some more useful information